# Debug statements firing only intermittently in .Net Micro Framework simple LED project

Tags: .net-micro-framework

I have a very simple .Net Micro Framework LED project (running on netmf 4.2 GHI code on an ARM Cortex-M4 CPU). Here is the relevant code:

```
using Microsoft.SPOT.Hardware;
```

[…]

```
OutputPort _RedLED;
OutputPort _GreenLED;
OutputPort _BlueLED;
```

[…]

```
_RedLED = new OutputPort(GHI.Hardware.FEZCerb.Pin.PB15, false);
_GreenLED = new OutputPort(GHI.Hardware.FEZCerb.Pin.PB14, false);
_BlueLED = new OutputPort(GHI.Hardware.FEZCerb.Pin.PB13, false);
```

[…]

```
for (var i = 0; i < numTimes; i++)
{
    Debug.Print("Go white ...");
    _RedLED.Write(true);
    _GreenLED.Write(true);
    _BlueLED.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Debug.Print("Go dark ...");
    _RedLED.Write(false);
    _GreenLED.Write(false);
    _BlueLED.Write(false);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Debug.Print("Go red ...");
    _RedLED.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _RedLED.Write(false);
    Debug.Print("Go green ...");
    _GreenLED.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _GreenLED.Write(false);
    Debug.Print("Go blue ...");
    _BlueLED.Write(true);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    _BlueLED.Write(false);
}
```

When I run the code on the device the LEDs come on and off as expected but the output window in Visual Studio 2013 shows

```
Go white ...
Go red ...
Go green ...
Go blue ...
Go white ...
Go dark ...
Go red ...
Go blue ...
Go red ...
Go green ...
```

Why aren't all the debug statements making it through? Is Thread.Sleep the wrong 'pattern' to use?

Answer (score 0):

Your Thread.Sleep() function only affects the program's main thread. Since netmf program has a single thread, there is no apparent reason to catch a synchronization shift in output. It is possible that in debugging mode, another thread that utilized by IDE itself, causes this result. Though, your successfully compiled netmf code should be working without a problem in correct order on embedded device or emulator.