# Does repeating Thread.Sleep(200) and Thread.Sleep(1) do the same thing?

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-micro-framework

I am writing a .Net Micro Framework application that starts a timer and then does stuff each time the timer tick happens. Here's the code:

```
public void Run()
{
    var timer = new Timer(DoStuff, null, 120000, 120000);
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

So every two minutes the method DoStuff gets called. I need the while loop to prevent the application exiting. What are the implications of the choice of milliseconds passed into Thread.Sleep? Does a small value (like 1) make the application react faster to the timer? Does a larger value consume less CPU power?

========== EDIT ==========

I just found the call I should (probably) use instead of the while loop in this cut-down example on the [GHI page about .Net Micro Framework Timers](https://www.ghielectronics.com/docs/27/timers):

```
Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
```

I can add 'infinte' to my list of values to understand.

Comment: You should not be using `Sleep` here at all. Why did you decide to do that?

Comment: It seemed the obvious way to keep the application live and waiting for timer ticks. What would you place there instead David?

Comment: What kind of timer are you using? Personally, I think I'd probably get rid of the timer, and call `Thread.Sleep(120000)` in a `while (true)` loop.

Comment: David, that was my first attempt but I swapped to the timer partly because it looked better (but I may be backwards on that!) and partly to try a different approach on a debug output problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/21602049/575530 (BTW I love that my dictionary in Chrome want to correct stackoverflow.com to controversialist)

Comment: You typically use timers if you want a thread to do other work whilst waiting for the next tick. But if your thread can be idle until the next tick then pure `while (true)` and `Sleep` works well.

Comment: Hang on David, I am confused. You mentioned that I "should not be using Sleep here at all" and then go on to explain that I should instead be using "Thread.Sleep(120000) in a while (true) loop". This appears contradictory - perhaps I've misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious what you are trying to do here. Why not have your timer fire as often as needed and do your periodic work from the timer method?

As for Sleep, it has a certain granularity by default that follows the Windows timer tick, so you will not get a 1 millisecond resolution by default. Yes, calling Sleep 1000 times rather than once obviously costs more CPU power but the different probably isn't significant in most scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure that is obvious. What exactly is Thread.Sleep(n) doing?

Comment: @dumbledad Well, it executes code on the CPU. It's not a *lot* of code. But it is code. Apart from the work needed just to run these instructions, pressure on the thread scheduler etc., this also requires context switching - the OS has to get a free CPU core, stop it, save all its registers to memory, then it has to load your registers from memory and start your thread. Then you run the code tidbit to do while and Sleep, and give yourself up to another thread, requiring another context switch. You're not even guaranteed it will run X times, because Sleep can return in 1ms or 15 or ...

Comment: Thanks Luaan, that would make a great answer. @500-internal-server-error, I don't understand what you mean by "Why not have your timer fire as often as needed and do your periodic work from the timer method?" Isn't that exactly what my code does?

Comment: Perhaps you do do your work on the timer callback, which is fine, but if you don't have any additional logic processing in your main thread, then rather than looping with Sleep as you do here you should instead block that thread on an event, or similar, and only signal that event from the timer callback when you want to terminate. That would consume very little CPU power compared to what you are doing here.